# Oracle SQL Update multiple parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table which I'm trying to update the cells of based on multiple where clauses, but it's failing and I don't understand why. Can anyone look at this and help?

| UserID | Options | Sub_option | Parameters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Firstname | Rick |
| 1 | Name | Lastname | James |
| 1 | Mail | Autoreply | 0 |
| 1 | Mail | Autosignature | 0 |
| 2 | Name | Firstname | Rick |
| 2 | Name | Lastname | Astley |
| 2 | Mail | Autoreply | 0 |
| 2 | Mail | Autosignature | 1 |

```
UPDATE Our_users
   SET Parameters = CASE
       WHEN UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autoreply' THEN '1'
       WHEN UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autosignature' THEN '0'
END
```

When running this, it seems to update "Parameters" for all rows.
Can't I use "AND" in WHEN clause?

Comment: If the `UPDATE` does not have a `WHERE` clause it will update all rows.

Comment: @The Impaler not exactly. You can use ELSE.

Comment: @Rezu Using `ELSE` produces the same result, but has the potential of being prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `WHERE` clause to restrict the update operations to the specific subset you want.

For example:

```
UPDATE Our_users
   SET Parameters = CASE
       WHEN UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autoreply' THEN '1'
       WHEN UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autosignature' THEN '0'
   END
WHERE UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autoreply' 
   or UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autosignature'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not use `ELSE` for other rows which do not match which your `CASE`:

```
UPDATE Our_users
   SET Parameters = CASE
       WHEN UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autoreply' THEN '1'
       WHEN UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autosignature' THEN '0'
       ELSE Parameters
   END
```

This query works, but if you have too many data in your table it takes too much time with `ELSE`. It means you should filter your rows with `where`:

```
UPDATE Our_users
   SET Parameters = CASE
       WHEN UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autoreply' THEN '1'
       WHEN UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autosignature' THEN '0'
   END
WHERE UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autoreply' 
   OR UserID = '2' AND Options = 'MAIL' AND Sub_option = 'Autosignature'
```

Comment: I tried this, but my table have 3million + rows which caused heavy load.

Comment: Then you should add the first two rows in where clause